# Why is .each used with jQuery selector and then again with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following piece of code that I have amended to fit into my doc, and it works, but I don't understand why it uses .each twice?
My comments in the code below should show where I'm confused.

```js
function searchFunction(value) {
  //This cycles through each tr and runs the function
  $('#results tr').each(function() {
    var found = 'false';

    //$(this) then selects the tr and then runs through each tr (again!) for the If statement.    
    $(this).each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        found = 'true';
      }
    });

    if (found === 'true') {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
};
```

I've tried removing the second .each but the code breaks. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Code should work without the second each. Not sure why it would break when it is removed.

Comment: Can you share the markup that this applies to?

Comment: Would have made more sense if the inner one was `$("td", this)`. Also the coder does not seem to know about the boolean type.

Comment: I created a working test of this and commenting out the `$(this).each(function() {` and the `});` it still works.

Comment: Just to ensure, While removing the second .each() did you correctly removed the corresponding brackets associated with it?

Comment: As my mates above said the second loop is unnecesary your are iterating an array of  one element it makes no sense and it would make the function slower. just remove it and make sure you close brakets properly it has to work 100%

Comment: Thanks guys. it was a rookie error on my part. i'd removed the wrong set of brackets. i wish id asked earlier, i spent so long trying to understand this code!

Comment: Thanks guys. it was a rookie error on my part. i'd removed the wrong set of brackets. i wish id asked earlier, i spent so long trying to understand this code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner `$(this).each(...)` will actually loop over collection consisting of just one `tr`-element. So it's completely redundant in this case and the 2nd `each()` can be dropped.

Probably in the beginning the idea was to loop over each cell inside of each row, kind of:

```js
$('#results tr').each(function() {
  $(this).find('td').each(function() {
    //...
  });
});
```

but you can't randomly hide/show cells because that would break the table layout. Probably the author got that and removed the `.find('td')` piece :) Just an assumption...